# How to update the values of all custom element instances in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I began to use Web Components in Javascript. I have a class called VariantSelects and I want each instance to have the same value. So whenever something changes in instance A, instance B should receive the same value. How do I do that?

I minimized my code for presentation purpose. The actual amount of functions is more complex.

```html
<!-- instance A -->
<variant-selects></variant-selects>
<!-- instance B -->
<variant-selects></variant-selects>
```

```js
class VariantSelects extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.currentVariant = null;
        this.addEventListener('change', this.onVariantChange);
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        // do stuff
    }

    onVariantChange() {
        // should be updated in all instances
        this.currentVariant = 123;
    }
}

customElements.define('variant-selects', VariantSelects);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: switch to React. it has all that you need :)

Comment: @boki_bo Unfortunately, in this project I can't :/ Otherwise I would use VueJS

Comment: "*whenever something changes in instance A, instance B should receive the same value.*" - no it should not. Or at least, it's not the component that should be responsible for this. Make the code that creates the instances and puts them on your page do this setup.

Comment: @Bergi so should I select all VariantSelects instances (`document.querySelectorAll`) outside of the class and listen to a change event. And on change event, call some `update` function in each instance? Could you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: @Phillip Yes, exactly that. Same way you'd keep some text `<input>`s in sync. What event exactly to listen for, and whether to call a method or to assign a property, depends on your component though.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. I figured it out and posted my answer. Might not be the best solution but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, although this might not be the best solution...

```js
const allVariantRadios = document.querySelectorAll('variant-radios');
Array.from(allVariantRadios).forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', updateAllInstances)
});

function updateAllInstances(e) {
  allVariantRadios.forEach(instance => {
    instance.querySelector(`input[value="${e.target.value}"]`).checked = true;
    instance.onVariantChange();
  });
}
```

Comment: The ``instance.querySelector(`input[value="${e.target.value}"]`).checked = true;``, as well as the firing of the event (assuming that is what `onVariantChange()` does?) should be done by the component code itself. You should only need to do `instance.changeVariant(value)` or `instance.variant = value` or something like that in the loop.